# If two sequences have convergent subsequences, must their sum has convergent subsequence?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to solve the following problem:

Let {$a_{n}$} and {$b_{n}$} be two sequences of real numbers. Suppose that {$a_{n}$} has a subsequence convergent to a, and {$b_{n}$} has a subsequence convergent to b. Must the sequence {$a_{n} + b_{n}$} have a subsequence convergent to a+b?

Attempt:

The only thing I was able to do was to state definitions:

Let {$a_{n_{k}}$} be a subsequence of {$a_{n}$}. Then $$\lim{a_{n_{k}}} = a$$ means that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists$ K $\in \mathbb{N}$, s.t. if ${n_{k} > K}$, then $|a_{n_{k}} - a| < \epsilon$.

Let {$b_{n_{m}}$} be a subsequence of {$b_{n}$}. Then $$\lim{b_{n_{m}}} = b$$ means that $\forall \epsilon > 0$ $\exists$ M $\in \mathbb{N}$, s.t. if ${n_{m} > M}$, then $|b_{n_{m}} - a| < \epsilon$.

Thus for $L > max(K, M)$ {$a_{n_{k}} + b_{n_{m}}$} converges to a + b. But how do we know that such subsequence {$a_{n_{k}} + b_{n_{m}}$} exists in the original sequence {$a_{n} + b_{n}$}?

Comment: Before doing all that work on trying to write a complicated proof, why don't you try to find a simple counterexample? Counterexamples are often easier than proofs.

Comment: Hint: Find a counterexample.

Comment: I was trying to find counterexample for 30 minutes, but I was thinking in some weirdly wrong way...

Comment: Pick $$a_n=\begin{cases} 0&\text{if }n\text{ is odd}\\ \frac{n}{2}&\text{if }n\text{ is even}\end{cases}\\ b_n=a_{n+1}$$ Then, $\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n+b_n=+\infty$, which means that $a_n+b_n$ flat-out lacks convergent subsequences.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider
$$a_n=\begin{cases}0,&n\text{ even}\\
1, &n\text{ odd}\end{cases},\quad b_n=\begin{cases}1,&n\text{ even}\\
0, &n\text{ odd}\end{cases}.$$

Then both $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ have a subsequence converging to $0$, but clearly $(a_n+b_n)$ has no subsequence converging to $0$ as $a_n+b_n=1$ for all $n$

Answer (score 2):

Take your favorite sequence that diverges and take your favorite sequence that converges. Mix those two up into new sequences and see what happens.